# How can I use Xamarin.Forms in a NUnit Library project?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I wanted to test out some binding code using `BindableObject` in a NUnit Library project, but I keep getting the error

> You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.

The problem is, that based on the source code in the assembly browser, that function is only defined in `Xamarin.Froms.Platform.iOS`, which I do not have in the NUnit project. How can I write simple unit tests with `Xamarin.Forms`? Should I use a different project template, or somehow customize the build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `Xamarin.Forms` `1.2.3`, you can't*. The `BindableObject` code and the Layouting code require a `Platform` to be set, and the API for doing so is `internal`.

This is known, and could be solved in the future, by allowing a `MockPlatform` to be set for tests, or something similar.

<sub>*: Well, you **can**, if your Nunit project is also a platform project, and run on the divide or the simulator, and not ran by the unit runner directly.</sub>